# x:Reference cannot find x:Name in design mode - compiles and runs fine

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, markup

This is a design-time issue.  Once the code compiles and runs, the correct values are passed in.

1 - using as a ConverterParameter referencing a datagrid by x:Name (per MSDN info, this is correct).
2 - CANNOT use a binding with ElementName, as ConverterParameter is not a dependency property.  I guess I could create a dependency property, it just doesn't seem necessary, as at some point in time, the x:Reference is resolved.. Just not resolved at design time.

So I have the following code.  This is a template to allow for coloring of filtered column headers, so they are visually noticeable to the user:

```
<Converters:BGConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="150">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="testtest" Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference TestListView}}">                                        
                    <Label Width="90" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}},Path=Column.Header}"
                                Padding="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Button Content="Ok" Padding="12,0,12,0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The issue is with the "ConverterParameter="{x:Reference TestListView}" section.  Markup does not compile, "GUI" shows only "An Exception was thrown.  XamlObjectWriterException: Unresolved reference 'TestListView'.

Again, if I step through code and actually run the program, each header does in fact get passed in to the converter correctly, and header column colors are determined and displayed correctly.

Datagrid (the referenced object) is declared as follows (partial, no need for borderthicknesses or headersvisibility, etc...):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TestListView" />
```

Is there a way to fix the designer so it can determine and find the x:Name?  I have read the articles from 2009 saying that x:Reference was new and not actually part of Xaml, but that was 2009, it's nearly 2015.  In 6 years this should have either been accommodated or removed.

Any suggestions on how to get the compiler to recognize the x:Name without going crazy and declaring it as static, or creating a dependency property?  Since it's only markup, I can live with it as-is, it'll just drive my OCD crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x:Reference` is not officially supported in compiled Xaml, which is still based on the Xaml2006 spec.  Since it implemented as a markup extension and not a language enhancement, it will still work at runtime in some cases (though not all), but it is not supported by the designer, and there is no way to make it work short of somehow extending the designer yourself.

You could probably implement a custom markup extension that performs the same task as `x:Reference`, utilizing the same services, but which fails silently in cases where the required services are missing (e.g., when running in the designer):

```
[ContentProperty("Name")]
public class NameReferenceExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    [ConstructorArgument("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public NameReferenceExtension() {}

    public NameReferenceExtension(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceProvider");

        var xamlNameResolver = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlNameResolver))
                               as IXamlNameResolver;
        if (xamlNameResolver == null)
            return null; // fail silently

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Name is required when using NameReference.");

        var resolved = xamlNameResolver.Resolve(this.Name);
        if (resolved == null)
            resolved = xamlNameResolver.GetFixupToken(new[] { this.Name }, true);

        return resolved;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I thought it may be something like this.  Seems like a long time to go without updating specs, but alas, what can we do? lol.  Thanks.  I'll leave it open for a bit longer just in case someone has a workaround, but I'll mark it as answered before COB if no workarounds are posted.

Comment: Updated answer with a custom alternative to `x:Reference`, but since it uses the same underlying service, it won't produce a value when running in the designer (though it won't produce an exception, either).